# Select a pandas DataFrame column by indices given in another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe such as

```
df = pd.DataFrame({1: [10,20,30,40], 2: [50,60,70,80], 3: [90,100,110,120], "select": [2, 3, 1, 1])
```

I can get a series of values selected from each row  want to select values in each row corresponding to the column index given in the `select` column, like this:

```
df.apply(lambda r: r[r.select], axis=1)   # 50, 100, 30, 40
```

Is there a better way to do this that doesn't rely on `apply`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lookup`:

```
df.lookup(df.index, df['select'])
```

Output:

```
array([ 50, 100,  30,  40])
```

Comment: Now [deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html). Not clear what the new way is of doing this.

Comment: @Stuart The link you given has [an example](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup) of a replacement. This is a result of the discussion [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/42110)

Answer (score 0):

Since `DataFrame.lookup` is no longer available, something like this (adapted from [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup)) seems to be the best way:

```
def vlookup(df, lookup_series):
    idx, cols = lookup_series.factorize()
    return np.diag(df[cols].to_numpy()[:, idx])

print(vlookup(df, df["select"]))
```